# Separate list element while scraping from web with commas

Tags: java, json, web-scraping, jsoup, org.json

I'm scraping data from web, there are li element in one div, the interface in the web like this

```
 Job Description:
• Developing application programming interfaces (APIs) to support mobile functionality
• Keeping up to date with the terminology, concepts and best practices for coding mobile apps
• Using and adapting existing web applications for apps
• working closely with colleagues to constantly innovate app functionality and design
```

this is part of my scraping code for those section are shown below ( job and jobTtle is JSON Array)

```
Elements ele3=doc.select("div.job-sections div[itemprop=description] section#st-jobDescription");
for (Element element3 : ele3.select("div[itemprop=responsibilities] ul")) {
     String job_description=element3.select("li").text();
     job.put(jobTitle.put(new JSONObject().put("description",job_description)));
}
```

The output like this

```
{"description" : "Developing application programming interfaces (APIs) to support mobile functionality Keeping up to date with the terminology, concepts and best practices for coding mobile apps Using and adapting existing web applications for apps Working closely with colleagues to constantly innovate app functionality and design"}
```

but I want to separate every li element with comma, so the output should be like this

```
{"description" : ["Developing application programming interfaces (APIs) to support mobile functionality", "Keeping up to date with the terminology, concepts and best practices for coding mobile apps", "Using and adapting existing web applications for apps", "Working closely with colleagues to constantly innovate app functionality and design"]}
```

how could I solve this ? anyone can help?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the way you are storing the job responsibilities. You are creating JSON Object where your desired type is a JSON Array.

// JSON Array

```
Elements responsibilityElements = ele3.select("div[itemprop=responsibilities] ul li");

JSONArray responsibilities = new JSONArray();

for (Element responsibilityElement : responsibilityElements) {
     String description = responsibilityElement.text();

     responsibilities.put(description);
}

job.put("description", responsibilities);
```

// In A Single String

```
Elements responsibilityElements = doc.select("ul li");
//        Elements responsibilityElements = ele3.select("div[itemprop=responsibilities] ul li");

List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();

for (Element responsibilityElement : responsibilityElements) {
    lines.add(responsibilityElement.text());
}

String description = String.join(", ", lines);
job.put("description", description);
```

Comment: hmm got it for what you mean, but the problem is I can't separate the <li> element with comma, while I store it, the output shown one line all of the <li> element, I want make it separated by comma, How to do that ?

Comment: @aarons your expected output format isn't clear, in the question you showed that you wanted to have the content of `li`s in a JSON Array, please provide a sample output so I can help.

Comment: Thanks for your help, my expected output of my code look under this sentences "The output like this", but my expected output look like under this sentence "but I want to separate every li element with comma, so the output should be like this". It's clear I think.